# Regex word boundary alternatives inside parentheses does not work?

Tags: php, regex

There is something I could not understand with the word boundary.

```
$input="157-XYZ";
preg_match("/[^\d+\-]\bRDS|xyz|ABC\b/i", $input, $output);
```

The above `preg_match` matches XYZ in `$input`.

However, if I put the alternatives inside the parentheses `/[^\d+\-]\b(RDS|xyz|ABC)\b/i`, it does not seem to return anything. Can't I use parentheses here to retrieve the result from `$output[1]`?

Comment: currently you regex matches: `[^\d+\-]\bRDS` OR `xyz` OR `ABC\b`. So the string 'XYZ' of course is matched. Describe the pattern you want to match and maybe we can help you correct your attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex is wrong:

```
preg_match("/[^\d+\-]\bRDS|xyz|ABC\b/i", $input, $output);
```

Since: `[^\d+\-]` means match **everything except**:

1. a digit
2. a literal `+`
3. a literal `-`

You can just use:

```
preg_match("/^\d+\-\b(RDS|xyz|ABC)\b/i", $input, $output);
```

Comment: how can you possibly know that is what he's trying to match?

Comment: @OGHaza: I don't see any literal `+` in the question OR input but it is present in character class. Which is an indication that OP is trying to match `\d+`

Comment: How can you transform `[^\d+\-]` into `^\d+\-`? One's a negative character class, the other's an anchored sequence

Comment: @knittl: Check OP's input data. OP is probably trying to match `\d+\-` at the start and meant to use `(^\d+\-)` instead of `[^\d+\-]`

Comment: @anubhava Yeah I got confused with `[]`. Thanks for sorting that out.

Comment: Great to know I wasn't wrong in my interpretation though I was being crucified for that :) If it work for you then don't forget to mark it as accepted.

Comment: @anubhava Just to clarify my confusion, inside the square brackets, is it possible to make `[^\d+]` as one or more digits and not a digit or a literal +?

Comment: No that is not possible inside square brackets alone.

Comment: If you want to match one or more non-digits then use `[^\d]+` OR better `\D+`

Comment: @anubhava, my apologies, fair play ;) didn't notice `$input` initially.

Comment: @anubhava Then `^[\d\-]+\b(RDS|xyz|ABC)\b` or `^[\d]+\-\b(RDS|xyz|ABC)\b` should be fine too with my input. Am I right?

Comment: Yes both will work with your inputs but keep in mind that first regex will also accept -123 and second week only accept 123-